# Conditional format Cells in range based on count of specific symbol in string

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, conditional-formatting

Range A2:A2000 has values that should contain only 1 `@` symbol. I need conditional formatting for all cells in this range that contain more than one `@` symbol.

I have tried this:
`=SUMPRODUCT(LEN(A2:A2000)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A2:A2000,"@","")))>1`

but it does not seem to work.
Where have I lost my way?
I am currently using Google Sheets.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use your formula, but do not enclose it in sumproduct. An ordinary formula with relative references (i.e. not using dollar signs) that works for the top left hand corner of the range will work for the rest of the range because CF automatically adjusts the references as if you were dragging the formula down (in this case) or across.

```
=LEN(A2)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A2,"@",""))>1
```

[image]

There is no reason not to use regexmatch instead, except perhaps for compatibility with Excel.

Comment: Perfect. I guess I was rushing and panicking and looked right past that!! Thanks for the fast response and help. :)

Comment: Perfect. I guess I was rushing and panicking and looked right past that!! Thanks for the fast response and help. :)

Answer (score 3):

Try to use the following conditional formatting formula:

```
=REGEXMATCH(A2,"@.*@")
```

The regular expression "@.*@" Would check if the input holds two '@' characters with 0+ characters of any kind inbetween.

Apply to appropriate range `A2:A2000`

Comment: While this code snippet may be the solution, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-‌​code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.